# The feature steps are highlighted with yellow lines [warning] saying "Cannot find declaration to go"

Tags: pytest, gherkin, pytest-bdd

I'm using pytest-bdd framework and I have created the feature file but the steps are highlighted with yellow lines [warning] saying "Cannot find declaration to go". I'm using Pycharm community edition. installed Gherkins plugin too. Is there a way to solve this or any plugin which will solve this?
test are passing fine though

tried using Gherkins pluging. I'm expecting to use command+mousehover to navigate to respective step definitions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you in this case, but when I crash into this error in IntelliJ, I normally just reopen IntelliJ while the tab of the feature file is open =)

Maybe this helps :P